# Found seemingly useless partition on Linux

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I was about to add some unallocated space to my Linux partition using GParted, since I almost ran out of free space, when I noticed a 10 GB ext4 partition(nvme0n1p4) that doesn't seem to be used by anything really. I checked the contents, and all it has is the lost+found directory and another containing an examples.desktop file. Can I simply remove this partition and add the resulting space to my root partition(nvme0n1p6 in this case) If so, how can I do this?

[GParted window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgMGj.png)

I am running dual-boot with Ubuntu 18.04.3 and Windows 10.

Comment: Check `/etc/fstab` to be sure it isn't referenced there.

Comment: I checked and it doesn't seem to reference it, so I suppose it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have used only standard drives shown as `/dev/sdx` and with such drives it is possible to do what you want. It should be possible with NVME drives too.

Editing partitions is risky, so I suggest that you start with a **backup** of everything that you cannot afford to lose.

Use **`gparted`** (when booted from a live drive) to

- remove the last partition, `/dev/nvme0n1p4`
- then expand the extended partition `/dev/nvme0n1p3` and
- after that expand `/dev/nvme0n1p6`

---

- You could also create a partition in the grey unallocated drive space and use that partition with NTFS for storage of data that you want to share between Ubuntu and Windows.

  It is best to store shared data in a **data** partition that is not a system partition for any of the operating systems. You might even want to reduce the size of the Windows partition (with Windows tools when running Windows), and create drive space to make that **data** partition bigger (than 9.77 GiB). After that you can move some data files from the Ubuntu as well as from the Windows partition to this **data** partition.

Comment: I followed the steps and everything worked fine. I also followed your advice and made the unallocated space use ntfs, in case I ever need to share some data between the 2 systems.

Comment: @VladIonescu, I'm glad that I could help you make it work :-)